# In open-search using java api to check if the index exists is not working

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-opensearch

To check if an index in open-search we have a function called exists.

`BooleanResponse response = openSearchClient.indices().exists(ExistsRequest.of(s -> s.index(indexName)));`

This is not working this getting the below error.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8EEe.png)

I installed the client using Apache HttpClient 5 Transport.
[client](Installing the client using Apache HttpClient 5 Transport)
Using opensearch.client: 2.4.0
gradle version: 8.1.1
java version: 17
springboot version: 3.1.1

I also tried using OpenSearchIndicesClient still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just cut the part from `.exists` somewhere else and try adding the same by hand. I had the same error and it was solved after I added it manually.